# Filtering through a list of lists of strings to get a list of lists of strings with a certain length

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, list-comprehension

I've got the following function, which takes two lists and matches each element with each element and returns a list of lists of strings.

```
matchChars:: [t] -> [t] -> [[t]]
matchChars x y = [[a,b] | a<-x, b <-y]
```

Now I want to modify the function, so that the strings in the list of lists don't overcome a certain length. 
For example: lets say `matchChars` produces the Output `[["aaa", "bbbb"],["c", "dd"]]`. I want to filter out all the sublists where the two strings together have a length of 7 or higher. So in this example `["aaa", "bbbb"]` would be filtered out.

I already tried:

```
matchChars:: [t] -> [t] -> [[t]]
matchChars x y = takeWhile ((<= 7) . length) [[a,b] | a<-x, b <-y]
```

But this doesn't work as it iterates over the length of the sublists and not over the string length. Does anybody have an idea how to solve my problem?

Comment: To me it appears that as currently written, `matchChars` can only produce lists of length 2.  It seems quite similar to [zip](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zip) , except that it returns a list of short lists instead of a list of pairs. Is this what you want ?

Comment: @jpmarinier I didn't use zip because it doesnt match each element with each element and only zips the elements on the same index.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I thought about that, but I don't want to remove stringy from x and y before they were matched, because I may loose valid pairings this way, if I remove strings of the length minor 7.

Comment: @T.Naz sorry, I deleted my comment as I realised I'd misread what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: You want to `filter` the resulting list (`takeWhile` stops taking when the condition fails, even if later elements fulfil it again). The predicate you use should take a list `[a, b]` and check the combined length of the two strings. Is that enough of a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, I think that `filter` is more appropriate than `takeWhile`, just like Robin.
Like this:

```
 λ> 
 λ> myFilter = filter (\[ls1, ls2] -> (7 > (length ls1 + length ls2)))
 λ> 
 λ> myFilter  [["aaa", "bbbb"],["c", "dd"]]
 [["c","dd"]]
 λ>
```

Function [takeWhile](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:takeWhile) is solely for getting an initial and **contiguous** segment of items that satisfy your predicate.